# Regex in Python: splitting on whitespace character in between two words that start with a capital letter

Tags: python, regex

In my NLP pipeline, I need to split titles from body text. Titles always consist of a sequence of capitalized words without any punctuation. The titles are separated from the body text using two whitespace characters `\n\n`.

For example:

```
This Is A Title

This is where the body starts.
```

I want to split the title and body text on the whitespace using Regex in Python, such that the result is: This Is A Title, This is where the body starts.

Can anybody help me to write the right Regex? I tried the following:

```
r'(?<=[A-Z][a-z]+)\n\n(?=[A-Z])'
```

but then I got the error that lookbehinds only work with strings of fixed length (but they should be allowed to be variable). Note that I cannot use r'\n\n' because line separators also occur in the body text (so this would result in too many splits).

Many thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Why not just split on `\s`?

Comment: How about just `r'\n\n'`?

Comment: I have line separators in the body text too, so that would also split parts of my body text. I'll add this to the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match the title followed by 2 newlines, and for the body match all lines that are not a title pattern using 2 capture groups instead of splitting.

```
^([A-Z][a-z]*(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z][a-z]*)*)\n\n((?:(?![A-Z][a-z]+(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z][a-z]*)*$).*(?:\n|$))+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[A-Z][a-z]*` Match an uppercase char and optional lower case chars to also match for example just `A`
  - `(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z][a-z]*)*` Optionally repeat 1+ spaces and the same pattern as before
- `)` Close group
- `\n\n` Match 2 newlines
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?![A-Z][a-z]+(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z][a-z]*)*$)` Negative lookahead, assert that the line is not a title pattern
    - `.*` If the previous assertion it true, match the whole line
    - `(?:\n|$)` Match either a newline or the end of the string
  - `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1 or more times
- `)` Close group 2

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/srCm5r/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/wgwN3s).

```
import re

pattern = r"^([A-Z][a-z]*(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z][a-z]*)*)\n\n((?:(?![A-Z][a-z]+(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z][a-z]*)*$).*(?:\n|$))+)"

s = ("This Is A Title\n\n"
    "This is where the body starts.\n\n"
    "And this is more body.")
    
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
[('This Is A Title', 'This is where the body starts.\n\nAnd this is more body.')]
```

Comment: This fails if you have title not followed by body -- such as `The End` with no text following.

Comment: @dawg That is correct, you can solve that by making the body part optional like https://regex101.com/r/gP6jCR/1 but I did not do that because the question is about the title and the body. But good point though.

Comment: @The Fourth Bird: this works, thanks!

Comment: @Thefourthbird one more question: what if my sentence starts with a number, such as 
  `1. This Is A Sentence`.  I noticed that this is also a pattern that occurs frequently.

Comment: @BjarneBrié In that case you can make that leading part optional `^((?:\d+\.[^\S\n]*)?[A-Z][a-z]*(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z][a-z]*)*)\n\n((?:(?!(?:\d+\.[^\S\n]*)?[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[^\S\n]+[A-Z][a-z]*)*$).*(?:\n|$))+)`  See https://regex101.com/r/xtkl90/1

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this text:

```
txt='''\
This Is A Title

This is where the body starts.
more body

Not a title -- body!

This Is Another Title

This is where the body starts.

The End
'''
```

You can use [This Regex](https://regex101.com/r/Xeqt0H/1) and separate titles (as you have defined them) from body:

```
import re
pat=r"((?=^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*[ \t]*)+$).*(?:\n\n|\n?\Z))|([\s\S]*?(?=^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*[ \t]*)+$))"

>>> re.findall(pat, txt, flags=re.M)
[('This Is A Title\n\n', ''), ('', 'This is where the body starts.\nmore body\n\nNot a title -- body!\n\n'), ('This Is Another Title\n\n', ''), ('', 'This is where the body starts.\n\n'), ('The End\n', '')]
```

---

As The fourth bird helpfully states in comments, the first lookahead can be eliminated:

```
(^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*[ \t]*)+$)(?:\n\n|\n*\Z)|([\s\S]*?(?=^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*[ \t]*)+$))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UaJRpK/1)

Comment: You can omit the lookahead here `(?=^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*[ \t]*)+$).*` and just match it instead `(^(?:[A-Z][a-z]*[ \t]*)+$`